# Java com.jcraft.jsch.JSch session not getting disconnect

Tags: java, session, jsch

I am using jcraft JSCH package to do ssh to a HP router and execute some CLI commands.
After execution of commands I am calling session disconnect method. But this session disconnect method is getting hung.
Not getting any idea why this disconnect is getting hung.

The session is getting disconnect once the idle timeout of router is reached.
Here is my piece of code -

```
package HpRouter;
import java.lang.Thread;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;

import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;


public class HpRouter {

    String CIPHER_S2C_KEY_NAME = "cipher.s2c";
    String CIPHER_S2C_KEY_VALUE = "aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc";
    String CIPHER_C2S_KEY_NAME = "cipher.c2s";
    String CIPHER_C2S_KEY_VALUE = "aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc";
    String CHECK_CIPHERS_KEY_NAME = "CheckCiphers";
    String CHECK_CIPHERS_KEY_VALUE = "aes128-cbc";
    String BCFNNI_STRICCTHOSTKEYCHECKING = "StrictHostKeyChecking";
    String NO = "no";
    String OPEN_SHELL_CHANNEL = "shell";
    String USER_NAME = "username";
    String PCODE = "123456";
    String HOST_NAME = "1.1.1.1";
    String PORT = "22";
    
    
    public Session getChannelConnection() throws JSchException {
        String userName = USER_NAME;
        String password = PCODE;
        String hostName = HOST_NAME;
        int port = Integer.parseInt(PORT);

        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session = jsch.getSession(userName, hostName, port);
        session.setPassword(password);

        session.setConfig(CIPHER_S2C_KEY_NAME, CIPHER_S2C_KEY_VALUE);
        session.setConfig(CIPHER_C2S_KEY_NAME, CIPHER_C2S_KEY_VALUE);
        session.setConfig(CHECK_CIPHERS_KEY_NAME, CHECK_CIPHERS_KEY_VALUE);

        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
        config.put(BCFNNI_STRICCTHOSTKEYCHECKING, NO);
        session.setConfig(config);

        session.connect();

        return session;
    }
    
    public StringBuilder getChannelOutput(DataInputStream ins, Session session, Channel channel) throws Exception {

        String line = null;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        byte[] tmpBuffer = new byte[1024];
        try {
            while (true) {
                while (ins.available() > 0) {
                    int tmp = ins.read(tmpBuffer, 0, 1024);

                    if (tmp < 0)
                        break;
                    line = new String(tmpBuffer, 0, tmp);
                    sb.append(line);
                }


                if (channel.isClosed()) {
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (session != null) {
                session.disconnect();
            }
            channel.disconnect();

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception while getting Channel Output - ");
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            throw new Exception("Exception while getting Channel Output - ", e);    
        }
        return sb;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        HpRouter hpObj = new HpRouter();
        try {
            Session session = hpObj.getChannelConnection();
            Channel channel = session.openChannel("shell");
            channel.connect();
            
            DataOutputStream ops = new DataOutputStream(channel.getOutputStream());
            DataInputStream ins = new DataInputStream(channel.getInputStream());

            
            ops.writeBytes("quit" + "\r\n");
            ops.flush();
            
            StringBuilder sb = hpObj.getChannelOutput(ins, session, channel);
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            
        }


    }

}
```

Thread dump -

```
"main" #1 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=1272.29ms elapsed=37.55s tid=0x00007feb6c410000 nid=0x20f504 runnable  [0x00007feb7a452000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketClose0(java.base@11.0.20/Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.socketPreClose(java.base@11.0.20/AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:722)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.close(java.base@11.0.20/AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:601)
        - locked <0x000000043af0b0a8> (a java.lang.Object)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.close(java.base@11.0.20/SocksSocketImpl.java:1067)
        at java.net.Socket.close(java.base@11.0.20/Socket.java:1513)
        - locked <0x000000043aef9190> (a java.lang.Object)
        - locked <0x000000043aef4b60> (a java.net.Socket)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.close(java.base@11.0.20/SocketInputStream.java:249)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.disconnect(Session.java:1753)
        at HpRouter.HpRouter.getChannelOutput(HpRouter.java:76)
        at HpRouter.HpRouter.main(HpRouter.java:104)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None
```

Comment: The command should be "exit" and this is a *bad* thing to do: [} catch (Exception e) {}](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/94-ignoring-exceptions-is-dangerous)

Comment: Also, you should probably multithread the streams, as *while (ins.available() > 0) {* is not necessarily reliable. Google on "java streamgobbler"

Comment: @g00se I am connecting to router CLI mode, so I dont have "exit" command there.

Comment: You mean, if you're doing it at the command line, you type 'quit' and you're disconnected?

Comment: Yes. But same thing if I do via my code, the disconnect it getting stuck.

Comment: I would switch to multithreading it. I don't see why you're accumulating the response actually. You can just read it continuously and output it. You can start with the primitive `while((buf = in.read()) > -1) { System.out.print((char)buf); }`

Comment: Same result with ```while((buf = in.read()) > -1) { System.out.print((char)buf); } ```

Comment: @g00se from give thread dump, are you seeing any issue ?

Comment: *Same result with...* Changing to my code without using a dedicated thread will do nothing. Is that what you did?

Comment: @g00se I tried mult-threading as well.
But ultimately it is getting stuck in session.disconnect